# Multiple SQL Joins / Search in same table

Tags: ms-access

I am currently making a little software, and nearly done when i've hit a wall.

I got a table with "Receipts", which got the following fields: 
Id, Customer, Date, ReceiptNr, Product1, Products1_count, Product2, Products2_count, Product3, Products3_count, Product4, Products4_count, Product5, Products5_count.

For Each receipt which is filled, the customer can select 5 different Products 
for each receipt. (Products got its own little table). 
[Receipt Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zaRQ.png) -- 
[Create Receipt for a customer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zaRQ.png)

**My question is:** 
How do i make a search inside SQL, that provides me with all Receipt from a customer, where all products are grouped, with a total count. My problem is that a receipt can have the same product in multiple places, so i need to search all 1-5 products tables and link them together with the Count as well.

I got the following to work, but only with product 1 and Counter 1.

```
SELECT a.id, Sum(b.Emballage1_counter) AS antal
FROM Emballage AS a LEFT JOIN Kvittering AS b ON a.id = b.Emballage1
WHERE b.Kunde = 6
GROUP BY a.id;
```

I would like to: 
Show all Receipt for Customer
Group all products (1-5) into one for each, that exist. 
Sum the Counters for each products.

- Customer A

  - Product B - Total Count: 200
  - Product C - Total Count: 150

Regards
Matias

Comment: You should have another table ReceiptDetails where each product is its own record. This table is dependent on Receipts. Why limit to 5 products? Normalized structure allows any number of products. Otherwise, will probably have to involve UNION query or VBA code.

Comment: I got the products in it's own table. The Receipt it limited to 5 input, according to customer needs.. :/

Comment: You should still use normalized structure otherwise your filter/search will be more complicated. You should have table "Receipts" with ReceiptNo, ReceiptDate, CustomerID then table "ReceiptDetails" with ReceiptNo_FK, ProductID, Quantity. You say '1-5 products tables', did you mean fields?

Comment: Date is a reserved word, should not use reserved words as names for anything.

Comment: Hi June, Thank you. I ended up with creating a details tabel. And it make sense when thinking about it. Was just so blind on the project atm.. Thank you alot! :)